# pushViewController from a different view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on an app that has a menu on a different view(the one on the left) How can I change the view on the right by tapping on the items on the left?

[image: Split view screen]

Comment: The other view is in an UINavigationViewController?

Comment: It can be solved in to many ways and also it depends on what you have already on the left and right side. Probably others can anser too if you will write those components detailed

Comment: Yes the view is in a UINavigationViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assuming you have a view controller for each view such communication should be handle through `delegate`. Have a look to this [basic tutorial](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) for setting up `protocols` and `delegates`. The idea is that you make your navigation controller on the left conform to a protocol and you set the view controller on the right as a delegate to the navigation controller. In other word you will make the right view controller in charge to handle events that happens in the navigation controller.